# Django showing custom URLs to different users

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

How can I display different URLs to different users based on their user_id?
For example, when the user is logged in, in the dashboard user 1 with user_id 1 should have a button with a default URL like https://www.example.com/user_id so that his URL will be https://www.example.com/1 while user 2 with user_id 2 should see the URL https://www.example.com/2.

I have no idea how I could achieve that. Do I need to edit the models, views or URLS file and what do I need to add?

Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the user object (or just the user.id) from the view to the template (either as an argument in your function-based view or using a context-processor for your class-based views). In the template you add `{% url 'your_view' user.id %}` to the link in the button.

'your_view' should then accept int:user_id as an argument.